# CoCreateInstance in the MMDevice API returns error code 0x800401F0

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, audio, com

As in the title, I am getting an error code that is not in the documentation of [CoCreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615(v=vs.85).aspx). The specific error code is 0x800401F0.

Note: I am new to C++ and programming at this level in general. Trying to learn by building an audio visualization tool.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Mmdeviceapi.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain(
  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  int       nCmdShow
)
{
    const CLSID rclsid = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
    const IID riid = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator;
    IMMDeviceCollection* pEndpoints;

    // Create a device enumerator
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        rclsid,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL,
        riid,
        reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pEnumerator)
    ); 
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("%x\n", hr);
    }
    // Create a collection of endpoints
    // pEnumerator->EnumAudioEndpoints(
    //  eCapture,
    //  DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE,
    //  &pEndpoints
    // );

    // UINT deviceCount;
    // pEndpoints->GetCount(&deviceCount);
    // printf("%u\n", deviceCount);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compilation**
`gcc audio.cpp -lole32`

I am running a 64-bit machine. Not sure if that may be part of the issue.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error code 0x800401F0 is `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED` ("CoInitialize has not been called"). That suggests that you did not call `CoInitialize()` first.

That is, a thread needs to call `CoInitialize()` (or `CoInitializeEx()`) before calling `CoCreateInstance()` or any other COM call.  If you need graceful cleanup, you are supposed to release COM interface pointers, complete your COM activity, and call `CoUninitialize()` before exiting.